# Using FromSqlRaw() NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net-core, nullreferenceexception, razor-pages

I'm trying to access/use raw Sql script or use stored procedure in C# .Net Core Razor page.
I know my sql script/stored procedure works upon getting the script on debug mode and then trying it out in MS SQL Server Management Studio.

I always get NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on this code:

```
var bom = _context.Recipe
                .FromSqlRaw("EXEC sproc_GetBOM @itemcode", _itemCode)
                .AsNoTracking()
               .ToList();
```

This is my context

```
public partial class MyDBContext: IdentityDbContext
    {
        public MyDBContext()
        {
        }

        public MyDBContext(DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Recipe> Recipe { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=serverIp; Database=DB; Integrated Security = False; Trusted_Connection=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; User Id=UserId;Password=Password;");
            }
        }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
//
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: where is ```_context``` and ```_itemCode``` defined. Do you ever use ```OnConfiguring()``` ?

Comment: _itemcode is just a variable where I pass the parameter. I have my OnConfiguring() above, is it wrong?

Comment: I will check those links..thank you.